# How to create a field which shows a custom order based on two fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a field which shows an order based on two columns. I have one column with a code in and one with a date. There are many dates for each code, but I am trying to pick out the latest date for each code. The table below shows the two columns I have and the order column that I need to create.

```
code  date        order column
1      10/04/22      3
1      11/04/22      2
1      14/05/22      1
2      10/04/22      2
2      15/04/22      1
3      11/04/22      1
4      12/04/22      2
4      16/04/22      1
5      15/04/22      2
5      17/04/22      1
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: This idea has been asked and answered here dozens, if not hundreds, of times already. `ROW_NUMBER` is the solution here for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larnu and Sean have already stated, Row_number is your friend here.

Start with the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (code int, date date)
INSERT INTO #table
    VALUES 
     (1, '04/10/22')
    ,(1, '04/11/22')
    ,(1, '05/14/22')
    ,(2, '04/10/22')
    ,(2, '04/15/22')
    ,(3, '04/11/22')
    ,(4, '04/12/22')
    ,(4, '04/16/22')
    ,(5, '04/15/22')
    ,(5, '04/17/22');
```

Then we write the query with the row numbers. The magic here is in the partition by/order by. That partitions your data based on the code, so it takes the three 1s and puts the dates in descending order. It then numbers them 1, 2, 3 with the latest date being number 1. Then it does code 2...

```
SELECT code
     , date
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date desc) rn
  FROM #table
 GROUP BY code, date
 ORDER BY code asc, date asc;
```

And that gets us the result you asked for:

```
|code |   date   |  rn |
|:----|:---------|:----|
| 1   |2022-04-10|  3  |
| 1   |2022-04-11|  2  |
| 1   |2022-05-14|  1  |
| 2   |2022-04-10|  2  |
| 2   |2022-04-15|  1  |
| 3   |2022-04-11|  1  |
| 4   |2022-04-12|  2  |
| 4   |2022-04-16|  1  |
| 5   |2022-04-15|  2  |
| 5   |2022-04-17|  1  |
```

And then if you only want the max date for each code... keep only the ones where row number equals 1.

```
WITH CTE AS 
     (SELECT code
           , date
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date desc) rn
        FROM #table
      )
      SELECT code
           , date
        FROM CTE
       WHERE rn = 1
       ORDER BY code

| code |   date   |
|:-----|:---------| 
|  1   |2022-05-14| 
|  2   |2022-04-15|   
|  3   |2022-04-11|  
|  4   |2022-04-16|  
|  5   |2022-04-17|
```

Comment: Thank you, I had been trying rownumber but it wasn't working, I was doing it wrong. This answer helped me see where I was going wrong.